# Time Based Login

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In my .NET web application I need to implement time based Logins for students,The system should allow students to login only between 9 AM and 5 PM.  somebody please suggest me how to implement this,  which is better implementing using SQL time functions or using .net time methods?
If simply compare using normal time functions will it create when I host  the application on a remote server(out side My country)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are some users who are *not* students: (1) authenticate the user, (2) check the user's roles and if they are a student and attempting a login at naughty time then logout the user and display an appropriate message.

Using a single source for time in an application can reduce complications. I often use the database server as the source of time so that all timestamped data generated by the application can be correlated properly. UTC can be your friend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle loggingIn event of login control and check if DateTime.Now lays between 9AM and 5PM

```
void OnLoggingIn(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime loginTime=DateTime.Now;
    if (loginTime.Hour >= 9 && loginTime.Hour <= 17)
                //log in your user
            else
                //show error message about time
}
```

Comment: Just remember this is the time on the web server, not the database, and these things may be different